# Abstract class having no abstract methods

Tags: java, c#, vb.net, oop, abstract

It is a well established fact that abstract classes may or may not have abstract methods in it. But, once i was going through a website.
Link: http://www.indiabix.com/technical/dotnet/object-oriented-programming/6

I could find out the following- 
Just have a look at the highlighted part.
[image: Screenshot]

My question is, whether the highlighted part is false, as i am thinking. Or, it has some other meaning that is true and i have mistaken ?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe what they are trying to say is an abstract class without any abstract methods is the same as a regular class with a protected constructor.

Comment: That seems incorrect. Section, *10.1.1.1 Abstract classes*, of the C# Language Specification clearly states: "An abstract class is permitted (but not required) to contain abstract members."

Comment: By the way, why the "java" tag? This question doesn't appear to be about java at all.

Comment: "An abstract class is always public." - That is also wrong.

Comment: @JimMischel I dont think that the 'java' tag for this question is invalid. Even java has the concept of Abstract Classes with the same behavior as in C#. Pls Correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: @SrinivasCheruku: Whereas Java's abstract classes might be similar to those found in .NET, the linked article is specifically about .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you are reading has several mistakes including the one you highlighted.

> You must declare at least one abstract method in the abstract class.

As Jim Minschel pointed out, the [C# Language Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) explicitly state that an abstract class is **not** required to have abstract members.  As your quoted source said `method` it is doubly wrong.

> An abstract class is always public.

This is also completely wrong.  An abstract class can be private, protected, protected internal, internal, or public.

For example, this code is perfectly fine:

```
 public class A
 {
      //Private and Abstract!
      private abstract class PrivateAbstract{}

      private class B : PrivateAbstract{}
 }
```

So given that the article has gotten wrong 2 out of 5 statements, I would recommend you find a different source for information on C#.  Perhaps Rob Miles's free [The C# Programming Yellow Book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895319/formatexception-on-datetime-parseexact)